# Floating Action Button in two Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, floating-action-button

I want to put a Floating Action Button (FAB) with 2 actions (the same for both Fragments) in 2 Fragments. The problem is I have only one Activity and many Fragments (more than these 2). What is the best way of doing this? Creating the FAB in the main XML or duplicating it in both Fragments?

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently working on an app with some similar issues, here is what I've done.

I started with the Android Studio Navigation Drawer Activity Template (create new activity and select the one for the Navigation Drawer). It created a FAB on top of the Activity's main content layout. Inside that layout I have a container where I swap Fragments in and out. When I don't want the FAB to show, I call [FloatingActionButton.hide(...)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#hide()) in the Activity and then [FloatingActionButton.show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html#show()) when I want it back.

This requires you to know which Fragment is currently visible so you should provide a tag when setting up your Fragment transaction:

```
getFragmentManager()
    .beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, EditTaskFragment.newInstance(true), FRAGMENT_EDIT)
    .addToBackStack(null)
    .commit();
```

Where `FRAGMENT_EDIT` is defined as:

```
private static final String FRAGMENT_EDIT = "edit";
```

When you commit the transaction you can call the FAB `show` or `hide` methods. Note that this may also require you to listen to the back button pressed event:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0){
            EditTaskFragment editFragment = (EditTaskFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_EDIT);
            if (editFragment != null && editFragment.isVisible()) {
                // coming back from edit, reset fab to add icon
                setFabIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_24dp);
            }
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        } else if(null == mTaskFragment || !mTaskFragment.cancelRefreshData()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

`setFabIcon` is used to hide the FAB (shrink animation), change the icon, then show it again (grow animation):

```
private void setFabIcon(final int resId) {
    fab.hide(new FloatingActionButton.OnVisibilityChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onHidden(FloatingActionButton fab) {
            fab.setImageResource(resId);
            fab.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Inside the Activity's `onCreate` method I setup a click listener for the FAB and check which fragment I should pass the call to:

```
fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Fragment currentFragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        String tag = currentFragment.getTag();
        switch (tag) {
            case FRAGMENT_TASKS:
                Snackbar.make(view, "Task creation is...under construction", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_TURNS:
                ((TurnFragment) currentFragment).takeTurn(view);
                break;
            case FRAGMENT_EDIT:
                ((EditTaskFragment) currentFragment).saveTask();
                break;
            default:
                Log.e(TAG, "Unhandled FAB fragment tag " + tag);
                Snackbar.make(view, "Not sure what to do...my bad", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Note that each of the Fragments I call exposes a public method that the Activity is expected to call.

Comment: I got it working in a different way: in each fragment on method onCreateView, I put a code setting the visibility of the FAB to GONE or VISIBLE depending on the Fragment.
getMainActivity().mButton_adicionar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: That does seem simpler.